# how to upload images from csv file that have column with labels and urls of images in Azure machine learning by code

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a dataset(CSV) file that looks like this one column with an identifier and another with the URL of the image, and I need to download images to my storage in azure machine learning, maybe someone could help what is the core should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the sample code provided in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-1st-experiment-bring-data). Specifically, where it explains how to [upload data to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-1st-experiment-bring-data#upload).

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()
datastore = ws.get_default_datastore()
datastore.upload(src_dir='./data',
                 target_path='datasets/cifar10',
                 overwrite=True)
```

Comment: what about the images linked via URL in the CSV?